# What does driver rejects match -19 mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

When a driver ouputs

```
probe of [driver] rejects match -19
```

Linux error -19 means there is No such device.
Does this mean that the loaded driver doesn't find its device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding most recent Linux kernel, the error reported in OP comes following [some code in /drivers/base/dd.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L572) :

```
    if (dev->bus->probe)
        ret = dev->bus->probe(dev);
    else if (drv->probe)
        ret = drv->probe(dev);

    switch (ret) {
…
    case -ENODEV:
    case -ENXIO:
        pr_debug("%s: probe of %s rejects match %d\n",
             drv->name, dev_name(dev), ret);
        break;
…
```

In other words in case the probing returns ENODEV or ENXIO.

Since you tell 19 being reported, this is indeed [ENODEV](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L23) wich indeed means you are correct : **No such device**

---

Since you do not tell much about the driver / device… just in case it would be some personal development, please do consider the short notice right at the beginning of the code linked here-above :

> Sometimes driver probe order matters, but the kernel doesn't always
> have dependency information which means some drivers will get
> probed before a resource it depends on is available.  For example,
> an SDHCI driver may first need a GPIO line from an i2c GPIO
> controller before it can be initialized.  If a required resource is
> not available yet, **a driver can request probing to be deferred by
> returning -EPROBE_DEFER from its probe hook**

Comment: you can install the [`errno` package](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/errno.1.en.html) and run `errno 19` which will prints out the error name `ENODEV 19 No such device`